# CKEditor : How to enable custom plugin button when in "Source" mode

Tags: javascript, button, plugins, ckeditor, toolbar

I have successfully integrated **CKEditor** into my project and have just built my first *"Hello, world!"* type plugin. The plugin works great in "wysiwyg" mode, but as soon as switch to **"Source" mode**, the plugin becomes automagically **disabled**.

No amount of coercion on my part has been able to keep the plugin button enabled. I know this is possible because by default, the "Select All" and "About" toolbar buttons in CKEditor are enabled for both wysiwyg and source modes.

I've seen references  to a **"modes" setting for toolbar items**, but have been unable to uncover the required syntax. Here's an unsuccessful example of what I've tried by editing my own **customConfig** file:

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'custom', items: ['HelloWorld'], modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 } },
    { name: 'about', items: ['About'] }
];
```

This doesn't work either:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'custom', modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 } },
    { name: 'about' }
];
```

How can I make a CKEditor plugin toolbar button enabled for both modes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. Through trial & error I found some syntax that works.

There may be other ways to do this, but this is what worked for me:

**config-text.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'custom', items: ['HelloWorld'] },
        { name: 'about', items: ['About'] }
    ];

    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'custom' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];
};
```

**plugin.js**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add("helloworld", {
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.addCommand("helloWorld",
            {
                // Enable the button for both 'wysiwyg' and 'source' modes
                modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
                exec: function (editor) {
                    alert("Hello, world!");
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton("HelloWorld", {
            label: "Hello World",
            command: "helloWorld",
            icon: this.path + "images/helloworld.png"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with ckeditor 4:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.getCommand('myPlugin').enable();
```

With this little JS you can react on nearly every event and enable the button you need.

Source: [ckeditor Forum](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Enabling-plugin-buttons-in-the-toolbar-when-the-editor-is-in-readonly-mode.)